# need clarification about LayoutAnimation

Tags: react-native

I've been trying to understand how to use LayoutAnimation and the docs haven't been very helpful.
is there a better source?  anyways here is this code which demonstrates the 3 different types of animations with layoutAnimation. It is an app with 3 buttons and 3 boxes which move across the screen differently.  I am failing to understand what causes the boxes to animate. I don't see a function call making it animate. I only see conditional statements in the style attribute.   the attribute seems to know nothing about the layoutAnimation. Yet it does animate.

here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Platform,
  UIManager,
  LayoutAnimation,
  StyleSheet,
  Button
} from "react-native";

if (
  Platform.OS === "android" &&
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental
) {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}

export default function App() {
  const [firstBoxPosition, setFirstBoxPosition] = useState("right");
  const [secondBoxPosition, setSecondBoxPosition] = useState("left");
  const [thirdBoxPosition, setThirdBoxPosition] = useState("left");

  const toggleFirstBox = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    setFirstBoxPosition(firstBoxPosition === "left" ? "right" : "left");
  };

  const toggleSecondBox = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
    setSecondBoxPosition(secondBoxPosition === "left" ? "right" : "left");
  };

  const toggleThirdBox = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
    setThirdBoxPosition(thirdBoxPosition === "left" ? "right" : "left");
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>


      {/* button demonstrating easing animation*/}
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title="EaseInEaseOut" onPress={toggleFirstBox} />
      </View>
      
      {/* button demonstrating linear animation*/}
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title="Linear" onPress={toggleSecondBox} />
      </View>
      
      {/* button demonstrating spring animation*/}
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button title="Spring" onPress={toggleThirdBox} />
      </View>


      {/*The three boxes demonstrating animation types*/}
      <View
        style={[
          styles.box,
          firstBoxPosition === "left" ? null : styles.moveRight
        ]}
      />


      <View
        style={[
          styles.box,
          secondBoxPosition === "left" ? null : styles.moveRight
        ]}
      />

      <View
        style={[
          styles.box,
          thirdBoxPosition === "left" ? null : styles.moveRight
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  box: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 8,
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  },
  moveRight: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end"
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea (and the major gotcha) with LayoutAnimation is that it sets an animation for ALL subsequent layout changes until it's removed. It just works automatically with no additional setup.

Comment: wow okay, this explains why in the animation handlers, you have to use  LayoutAnimation.configureNext.   but how does react know which element is the one to be affected by the configuration?  In the app you can press all 3 buttons at the same time and each run their own style of animation